# Explanation of @Configuration @AutoConfigureAfter with Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, kotlin

I am a python dev and totally new to Spring boot and gradle. However i am fine with java and Trying my best with Kotlin. I was trying to run Spring Boot application(Kotlin) on localhost. Gradle build is working fine except these line

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration::class)
open class Assembly : WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter()
{
   .
   .
```

> No value passed for parameter resourceProperties, mvcProperties, beanFactory....

I understand that `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` constructor expects these params but should they not be passed automatically through annotation `@Configuration` and `@AutoConfigureAfter` .

As i am totally new to spring boot i have no idea what is going wrong and where. As this code is already running in production so i am really confused about whether i am missing some local configuration or gradle conf or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` isn't intended to be used directly by application code. You should be extending [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) instead.

I suspect you've upgraded to Spring Boot 1.4. In that release, `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` changed from using field injection to constructor injection. This means that subclasses now need to call the super-constructor passing in the required arguments.

`@AutoConfigureAfter` only controls the ordering of auto-configuration classes and has no effect on dependency injection. It also only affects auto-configuration classes so may we'll be doing nothing on your `Assembly` class.

`@Configuration` doesn't really affect dependency injection either. Configuration classes can have dependencies injected, either into fields annotated with `@Autowired` or into their constructor. Previously, that constructor also had to be annotated with `@Autowired` but, [as of Spring Framework 4.3 (Spring Boot 1.4)](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3), the annotation is unnecessary if the class has a single constructor.

Comment: Got the idea. Thanks . specially for mentioning ```field injection to constructor injection``` in sb 1.4.